# Why are internal boundary conditions for the Laplacian equivalent to the presence of a source term?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, math-software, laplacian

Suppose we want to solve the Laplacian $\nabla^2\phi=0$ with $\phi$ vanishing at infinity. Suppose also that we want an extra boundary condition, say $\phi=1$ on some bounded region $R$ of space.

The PDE solving software package I'm using ([FiPy](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/)) doesn't support this. It only supports solving the Laplacian with boundary conditions in a region of genus 0. However, they [recommend](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/USAGE.html#applying-internal-boundary-conditions) getting around this by "adding source terms". The linked documentation is very unclear to me, but if I understand correctly, they're claiming that the original problem is approximately equivalent to solving:

$$\nabla^2\phi(x) - K1_R(x)\phi(x) + K1_R(x)=0\tag 1$$

Where $1_R$ is the indicator of $R$ and $K$ is some very large positive value, and $\phi$ vanishes at infinity. Why is this approximately equivalent to solving the original problem?

**Note:** Like I said, I'm not sure at all that (1) really is the equation they're getting at, but I think it's something close to that. I'm hoping someone can correct me if I'm misinterpreting the documentation.

Comment: You should be cutting R out of the domain entirely and enforcing a condition only on its boundary. In principle you can "homogenize" the boundary condition by subtracting off a function which satisfies the boundary condition. Doing this introduces source terms to the new PDE unless your chosen function also satisfied the PDE. But this is too cumbersome, you should be able to set internal boundary conditions for free.